# excel vba : why is this function looping infinitely?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the following function to search a worksheet for the last available blank row.

```
 Function findlastLog_Row() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1 'start at row 1

    Do Until Sheets("Log").Cells(i, 1) = ""
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    findlastLog_Row = i
End Function
```

Any ideas why its looping over and over.  It seems to start all over on the second to last line `findlastLog_Row = i`.  This last line is to return the value of `i`. Am I oversimplifying this?

Comment: Use this to find the last row http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: How do yo know that it is "looping over and over", and that it "*seems to start all over on the second to last line*"?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print findlastLog_Row
End Sub

Function findlastLog_Row() As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")

    With ws
        findlastLog_Row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Just a precaution, but `Integer` type might return an overflow error if the sheet has many rows.

Comment: @DavidZemens: Dunno how i missed that! Amended it

Comment: If the column you use this on has blanks you may get undesirable results.

Comment: @AxGryndr: What kind of undesirable results?

Comment: If you are trying to find the last row that has data to copy a range and column A only has values in row 1 through 10 but columns B, C and D have data from 1 to 15 you'll miss those 5 rows.

Comment: @AxGryndr: For that see the link that I posted in the comment right below the question :) Here the user wants to find the last row in Col A

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to Sheets("Log").Cells(i, 1).Value (hence the .Value at the end). .Cells() will return a Range object. I'm not entirely sure what the default property of a range is, but it might just not be the .Value property.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't have Excel at hand to verify. Maybe someone upvoted it for stimulating good practice? ;)